# Pressure in stokes flow

Tags: forces, differential-geometry, pressure, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, navier-stokes

In the stokes equation for an incompressible fluid, there is a pressure term that enforces the fluid to have $\nabla \cdot u=0$, where $u$ is the velocity field. The stokes equation reads:

$$\eta \nabla^2 u = -\nabla P +\nabla \cdot S$$

where $S$ is the stress tensor. If we want to solve the equation in a geometry with specific symmetries, does the pressure term (which is the Lagrange multiplier) need to obey those symmetries?

Let's say we want to find the velocity field in a 2D polar coordinate and we know that the velocity is only a function of $r$ and not $\theta$ and also $u_r=0$. So the velocity only has $\theta$ component. Does the pressure also need to be a function of $r$ only? or can it be a function of $\theta$ too?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say $S=0$. Then we gather from the equation that $\partial_\theta P$ does not depend on $\theta$ by using gradient and Laplacian in polar coordinates. Now, to calculate the pressure difference between two points we can use a line integral
$$
\int \nabla P \cdot \text{d}l\,.
$$
Do that along a circle and you'll find for the pressure difference found after going round to the same point
$$
0 = C \partial_\theta P
$$
with some non-zero constant $C$. From that we can conclude that $P$ does not depend on $\theta$.

If $S$ is nonzero, then it depends...

Comment: What if $S$ is non-zero but $S$ does not depend on $\theta$? So $S$ is only a function of $r$.

Comment: Remember that $S$ is a tensor! If components of $S$ in polar coordinates are only functions of $r$, we might (I haven't done the legwork) be fine. But you really would need to check by expressing the tensor and its components in polar coordinates and then doing something like the above...

Comment: Yes, I mean the components of $S$ are a function of $r$ only. @ 
kricheli

Comment: Not sure if the pressure difference around a circle needs to be zero as I think the pressure is only a Lagrange multiplier and does not have a physical meaning. I think it is the gradient of the pressure that has a physical meaning. Doing the calculations considering the full stress tensor in polar coordinate shows that the pressure can only be linearly dependent on $\theta$. If the pressure was a real physical quantity this could not be true, but since its gradient appears in the equation I think it could be linearly dependent on $\theta$ ($p= c \theta$). Am I making a mistake?

Comment: Hm, interesting point. I'm not sure about it, but I think by taking the divergence of the equation we find that $\Delta P = \partial_i \partial_j S_{ij}$, and if the right-hand side is sufficiently well-behaved, then shouldn't $P$ be continuous? For $S=0$ for example, $P$ would be analytic.